# Validating that input consists of alphabetical characters

Tags: python, string, exception

I have been trying to add some validation for users entering a new word to a text file.

The input must consists of letters only and I have got this working using if statements with `.isalpha()`, however I wanted to try and see if I could get it working using try, except and so far I have not got it working.

The try statement is allowing all input in no matter if it contains digits or spaces. I cant seem to spot where i've gone wrong.

```
def AddNewWords():
    List = []
    Exit = False
    while not Exit:
        choice = input("Please enter a word to be added to the text file: ")
        try:
            choice.isalpha()
        except:
            print("Not a valid word")
            continue
        else:
            List.append(choice)
            Exit = True
   Return List

AddNewWords()
```

Comment: `try` and `except` statements react to exceptions, but `isalpha` doesn't raise any (it returns a Boolean value instead). It's not clear exactly what you are trying to do, so I can't really offer any suggestions for how to fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`isalpha()` returns True/False, it doesn't raise any exception.

Try this instead:

```
choice = input("Please enter a word to be added to the text file: ")
if not choice.isalpha():
    print("Not a valid word")
    continue
List.append(choice)
Exit = True
```

FWIW, you can also rewrite your loop in a more compact way without using the exit variable, but rather `while True` + `break`:

```
while True:
    choice = input("Please enter a word to be added to the text file: ")
    if choice.isalpha():
        List.append(choice)
        break
    print("Not a valid word")
```

Answer (score 1):

There are many way to achieve your result without a `try` / `except` clause. However, raising a manual exception is a perfectly valid approach and can be applied with only a couple of changes to your code.

First, you need to ensure a `False` result for `str.isalpha` raises an error:

```
if not choice.isalpha():
    raise ValueError
```

Second, you should define explicitly the exception you are catching:

```
except ValueError:
    print("Not a valid word")
    continue
```

Complete solution:

```
def AddNewWords():
    L = []
    Exit = False
    while not Exit:
        choice = input("Please enter a word to be added to the text file: ")
        try:
            if not choice.isalpha():
                raise ValueError
        except ValueError:
            print("Not a valid word")
            continue
        else:
            L.append(choice)
            Exit = True
    return L

AddNewWords()
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to check if true/false not try the except since you wont get any exception. the code should be.

```
def AddNewWords():
    List = []
    Exit = False
    while not Exit:
        choice = input("Please enter a word to be added to the text file: ")
        if not choice.isalpha():
            print("Not a valid word")
            continue
        else:
            List.append(choice)
            Exit = True
    return List

AddNewWords()
```